# Event.stop within .each (prototype)

Tags: event-handling, prototypejs

I am struggling with function that should check form fields before submitting.
I have some select (dropdown fields) and a text field. None of them should be empty for submit.

The script http://jsfiddle.net/6KY5J/2/ to reproduce.

I check dropdown fields within .each and additional text field. Here is the function:

```
function checkFields(e) {
    $$('.dropdown').each(function (element) {
        if (element.selectedIndex === 0) {
            alert('Fill all dropdown fields!');
            Event.stop(e);
            throw $break;
            return;
        }
    });

    if ($('sometext').value == '') {
        alert('Fill the input!');
        Event.stop(e);
        return;
    }
    alert('OK!');
}
```

But I am not able to prevent further execution of the script if one of dropdown is empty. Event.stop(e) seems to to work for the input field only in the second part.

Desired behaviour:

1. Check dropdowns, if one is empty, **stop execution, do not make any 
   further checks**.
2. Check text input field **only if** dropdowns are not empty.
3. Submit **only if** everything if filled.

The issue is in step 1. My script does not stop here, alerts, but does not stop. Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkFields(e) {
    var dropdownsokay = true;
    $$('.dropdown').each(function (element) {
        if (dropdownsokay && element.selectedIndex === 0) {
            alert('Fill all dropdown fields!');
            Event.stop(e);   
            dropdownsokay = false;         
        }
    });

    if(dropdownsokay) { //only check textfield if all the dropdowns are okay
        if ($('sometext').value == '') {
            alert('Fill the input!');
            Event.stop(e);
            return;
        }
        alert('OK!');
    }

}
```

Comment: Have tried it http://jsfiddle.net/6KY5J/1/ Nope :( It does not stop to execute. It even does not stop if one drodown field is empty and checks every dropdown. In my first solution the iteration for dropdowns has stopped at least. The issue is further checks...

Comment: Please check the modifications.

Comment: You can also add a `throw $break;` inside the `each()` if one of them fails to break out of the each loop and not keep running through each of the dropdowns